# android cursor movetofirst performance issue

Tags: android, database, performance, optimization, cursor

i am trying to optimize my application. I noticed that cursor.movetofirst() method somehow slowing the performance of my code.

```
Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getDayInfo(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myCalendar.getTime());
```

above line executes in **10 ms** in *2.1 emulator*, and

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
```

this line took about **1.6 seconds**. I made little search about this. Somepeople say make it in another thread or in asynctask, but this will make the code more complicated.
I 'm just trying to figure out what is actually happening to this cursor.
Can anyone simplify or give a hint about database performance increase related to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is natural, that moveToFirst() method gets much more time that other code. The data enquariyng actually takes place, which invokes database communication, data reading and so on. You actually can't do anything with it. The advice was right - move all the long operations to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: do you mean all long operations that a single row query?

Comment: i felt to add an important comment after finding out the reason that table has columns id, foreign_id, date and i had created index for date only. But soon realized that i have sould created index on foreign_id and date columns together. Here is the query: <b>CREATE INDEX idx ON mytable (foreign_id, date)</b>. And column order is important.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since this was marked answered but you never really got a great answer here. Even on a very large table a single row query should usually take much less than 1.6 seconds. The reason it's slow is that you don't have an index for the column(s) that you are querying on so it has to scan the entire table to find those values. If you create an index you can cut the time down to a fraction of a second.

Comment: yes it's been a while but i later created an index for that column that increased my original data but no performance difference observed. Maybe it is about create index logic with text column which is not unique.

Comment: I concur - after testing adding an index doesn't decrease the time for moveToFirst()

Comment: Sme issue to me, but only the first time I am fetching data. Every next  fetch on same table , but with different where clause is much faster. It seems to me that the data should be touched first, then it gets more performant.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset held by the cursor is large, moving the cursor around takes time. You have to perform such data-intensive operations on a separate thread. Using an `AsyncTask` might make your code a tiny bit complex but it's worth it. This against the user thread being blocked at the cost of a broken UI experience.

Comment: thanks a quick replay but resulting dataset is just a single row, but total database contains thousands of row. I think it is not about the dataset held. Query returns a single row with 10 columns though.