# Cursor in Android (SQLite)

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, cursor

I have a problem with the cursor in Android...

```
public int getCountNameContainWord(String word){
    long time1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Cursor cur = bdd.query(TABLE_IDF, new String[] {"COUNT(idfs)"}, "idfs LIKE '"+word+"%'", null, null, null, null, null);
    long time2=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("time query : "+(time2-time1));
    if(cur!=null){
        cur.moveToFirst();
        long time3=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time move cursor : "+(time3-time2));
        int i=Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(0));
        return i;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

results :

> time query : 3
>
> time move cursor : 3784

Move cursor is very slow and I do not know why... There is only one result row...
Do you have an idea to make it faster? Usually, it takes only some milliseconds...

PS : sorry for my bad English but i am a French :/

Comment: I'm not saying this is the answer, but I recommend against inserting I/O when you're timing operations. :-)  Does it change at all if you move all the println() statements after the if..else block?  (You'll have to move the return as well to test this.)

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:***
Ok, I found out that `moveToFirst()` takes long time because it does the actual database communication. There is not much you can do about it. If it is causing performance problems and blocking your UI, you can try to move it into a `AsyncTask`.

[android cursor movetofirst performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953656/android-cursor-movetofirst-performance-issue)

How big is your table? You can try to add index to `idfs` and check if it makes a difference.

---

I'm sure `System.out.println` takes a lot of time. So try this:

```
public int getCountNameContainWord(String word){
    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time2, time3 = 0;
    Cursor cur = bdd.query(TABLE_IDF, new String[] {"COUNT(idfs)"}, "idfs LIKE '"+word+"%'", null, null, null, null, null);
    time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(cur!=null){
        cur.moveToFirst();
        time3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int i=Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(0));
        System.out.println("time query : "+(time2-time1));
        System.out.println("time move cursor : "+(time3-time2));
        return i;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's the same: 
time query : 4
time move cursor : 3652

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is here [Why Cursor Operation is taking so much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289369/first-time-cursor-operation-is-so-slow-when-query-bulk-data-how-to-solve) and I quote

> ok, guys, i have not been here for acouple days.And i found the solution that is you have to create index for your table which will improve the query speed.

Comment: no, adding an index doesn't decrease the time it takes for moveToFirst() , it decreases the query time itself